# Getting Error 500 after composer update from ssh

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu-16.04, laravel-8

I used to use forge for deploying my laravel application to production. I recently deregisted forge and I wanted to deploy via ssh to ubuntu server on my own.

I did composer update and I pull changes to my server via ssh; but after these my application started to give error 500. I did every thing I searched may be useful such as commands below but nothing worked.
does any one know why am I facing is this error? in local environment every thing works properly and my laravel project worked properly before ssh and composer update.

these  are the steps I have go through but nothing worked:

1. deleting vendor folder and reinstalling composer
2. changing permisions for bootstrap and also for the whole project :

> sudo chgrp -R www-data storage bootstrap/cache

> sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache

3. run  composer dump-autoload
4. php artisan config:cache
5. composer update and sudo composer update
6. I also tried these commands but none of them worked:

   ```php
       php artisan view:clear
       php artisan config:cache
       php artisan cache:clear
       php artisan config:clear
   ```

I am using laravel 8

my .env file also exists and every thing are set there

when I turn on debug mode the error of the application page is like this:

> Target class [hash] does not exist.
> [image]

please helpme if any one has any experience on this problem.

Comment: can't help without more details, what's your route, where is hash? what's other debug info?

Comment: It's hard to help you without context, but make sure you didn't make mistake in class name (like using new hash, when class is named Hash) or that you didn't forget to use path.to.class;

Comment: I have not used Hash any where, it just shows in the debug mode. when I turn off debug mode the page shows error 500

Comment: try `php artisan optimize:clear` and after that `php artisan cache:clear`. hope can help you

Comment: @ArashYounesi thanks for reply, I did this now but no change, still error 500 appears

Answer (score -2):

From russia /ivorycoat

- delete vendor
- composer update
- .env.example copy and create .env

```
php artisan cache:clear 
php artisan config:clear
php artisan key:generate
php artisan serve
```